# How to properly parse values from this POST body String (returned from spark.RequestWrapper.getBody())

Tags: java, spark-java

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I was looking for spark.RequestWrapper.getBody() on here and couldnt find what I was looking for. Basically, when I make a post request with 3 body values (name="Something, id="Something", someNumber=1) then call `getBody()`, I receive the following.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryAFbSXBcWNVOAmQFo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

"Something"
------WebKitFormBoundaryAFbSXBcWNVOAmQFo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

"Something"
------WebKitFormBoundaryAFbSXBcWNVOAmQFo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="someNumber"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryAFbSXBcWNVOAmQFo--
```

I believe this actually comes from `IOUtils.toByteArray(servletRequest.getInputStream())`, and is cast to a string. Considering it's from servletRequest, I figured this is a pretty common problem, but haven't found a library or solution yet.

Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S. - If this is a duplicate, my apologies. Feel free to flag it and I'll be on my merry way!

Edit - Not Apache Spark. This one: http://sparkjava.com/

Comment: what is your client sending. mine type, content-type.

Comment: Are you trying to handle multi-part request? If so, this is probably what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29373468/396092

Answer (score -1):

When you declare a route, you declare a parameter to access the request. Use this in order to get the request body, like request.body() or request.bodyAsBytes(), as it's done in the [documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#request). If you're still unable to get a better format, then you'll have to format it yourself in your client application. The best content-type to use for this would be application-json.